# Copy contents of html

Tags: google-chrome, browser

Using the browser Chrome, I want to copy some values from a webpage.

For example, the given link https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp. For the values of the drop down options, I right click it and "Inspect Element", it shows the options.

Is there a way to directly copy them (to clipboard), not checking the page source code, or using any scripts? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: @dsstorefile1, thank you for the comment. this's a bad example... they are there when I View the Page Source. I am looking for a way to copy them directly instead of viewing the source (question edited accordinly)

Comment: It is strange that you included a screenshot of the page source when it is irrelevant. You could simply say the drop down has values, you know it's in the page source but you don't want to have to go to page source.

Comment: You ignored my comment and worded your question very wrongly.  Judging by what you wanted, it shows that you did not realise that element inspector IS showing page source.. You were clearly happy to manually copy from the source shown in the element inspector. What you meant was without clicking "view..page source".  So element inspector showing source is fine.  You could have asked how do you copy from element inspector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking to "scrape" the page.
There are extensions for Chrome (specified in your question) to do just that.

Here is one I found after googling Chrome Web Scraper.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-scraper/jnhgnonknehpejjnehehllkliplmbmhn?hl=en

Comment: Please read [how to recommend software in answers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers), particularly the bits in **bold**; then edit your answer to follow the guidelines there. Thanks!

Comment: @bertieb  He is more than clear enough   For example, your bossy link says "Title of the product with a link to the download/main page."  He did that.   Giving an overview or personalising it really isn't that necessary. And he said he just found it so he probably hasn't used it himself.  It's not reasonable to demand somebody to go into how to use it if they haven't used it themselves.

Comment: @barlop thank you for your input. My intention is to point users are community requirements which they might not be aware of, I'm sorry if that seems bossy to you; if it helps, it was not be me who authored the guidelines. If you have a better phrasing I would welcome it :) The guidelines do exist for a reason however, and the answer notes *"items in bold are required"*. There is a strong community consensus behind them, dating from 2012. Suggesting that OP download untried software *might* work better as a comment, but it is not a high quality answer that will help future users.

Comment: @bertieb well, A)the site has had a history of telling people not to ask shopping questions, and since somebody gave an answer that you refer to as recommending software, it sounded a bit like you were suggesting the answer was illegitimate / needs adjusting in order to be fit for the site.   If you'd said that the answer is good though could be improved if xyz, then that'd have been clearer.

Comment: @bertieb that is the main thing, and   B)Also besides that, it's clear that the person posting the answer hasn't tried the thing. If they clearly had and if it was something that might be tricky too, then I might certainly push them include some screenshots or pointer on how to use it. One could say "Look, if you are going to post an answer without trying the thing then you should make it a comment". But, he hasn't got the rep to comment on somebody else's post, so it's fine imo.

Comment: @barlop thank you for taking the time to reply. As I understand it, the reason for the guidelines in the link I included was to avoid low-quality answers which `software-req` questions garnered in the past. You have longer experience on here than I do so I would be happy to be corrected on that! :) The guidelines say words to the effect *"don't recommend software you haven't tried"*, which this answer falls afoul of; however it has helped the querent, so it was useful to them at least.

Comment: @bertieb Well, I use intelligence rather than just considering guidelines. and sometimes something isn't in line with what the powers that be say should be but i'm not going to call them out on it unless I agree too.  I think his answer as is, was ok, for the reasons i've mentioned.

Comment: @MarkK did you actually use this answer , or did you use the thing you posted, or something else ?

Comment: @barlop, I tried the way Bob K suggested. And finally used the way I posted.

Comment: @MarkK  did the extension bob posted solve it, and if so, why did you prefer what you found over it?

Comment: @MarkK I can see now why you preferred your solution over that extension, but you worded your question very wrongly

Comment: @barlop,  Bob K's answer came first before the way I found. I put it on for the purpose of sharing of knowledge, wishing to help other who has the similar question with choices for solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are some pages that you cannot see the values in HTML source code. This is a way somewhat helpful.

As an option, it seems also possible directly copy the element from the element window. You can select either line in the wanted element and copy it, but not multiple (Ctrl, or Shift for multiple selection doesn't work).

the trick is to select and copy the parent line. in the example, copy the line:

**copy either the OuterHTML or Element**

```
<select>...<select> == $0
```

Paste it to Notepad or any editor, you will get:

```
<select>
  <option value="0">Select car:</option>
  <option value="1">Audi</option>
  <option value="2">BMW</option>
  <option value="3">Citroen</option>
  <option value="4">Ford</option>
  <option value="5">Honda</option>
  <option value="6">Jaguar</option>
  <option value="7">Land Rover</option>
  <option value="8">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="9">Mini</option>
  <option value="10">Nissan</option>
  <option value="11">Toyota</option>
  <option value="12">Volvo</option>
</select
```

So it's almost there.